# Login Failed: invalid_key: Android Key mismatch

Tags: android, facebook

I get this error when i click the login button of facebook in my android application

"Login Failed: invalid_key: Android Key mismatch. Your key "YLYMBqpjl/OenePeQNf4DORUfR8" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings, check your app settings at www.facebook.com/developers"

I have gone through link: http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/
and many more, and found out that when using android-facebook sdk on a device (it works fine on emulator) if there is a facebook application already installed on that device it gives this error. to solve this generate a hash key and add it to the facebook application settings, which i did properly, but still i get the same error.

where does this key - "YLYMBqpjl/OenePeQNf4DORUfR8" come from in my error message??

it was working fine on emulator, i could login and post on my wall and get userID, email etc...but on device i get this error

Comment: Can you please post some code as well?

Comment: code is : i used the facebook-android sdk and refered it in Simple (which is a sample app given with the sdk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key is :  "**YLYMBqpjl/OenePeQNf4DORUfR8**"

paste this key in Native Android App Which Mark as a green Border.

[image]

Comment: but i read somewhere key contains some characters like "=" and "+" and thats what i got while generating the key using keytool...shouldnt i use that in app settings??

Comment: whatever key you got using keytool paste it here.

Comment: Yes if you have put this key there then it should work.strange to see its not working.why don't you try both keys.Facebook says if you don't generate key using keytool then you should put the keys which you got in error message.I would suggest try to put both keys one by one and test which one works.

Comment: thanks to Vipul shah. Try the key which you get in error message, if the actual key which you have created using keystore doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@archie.bpgc it is because you are using the same key which tute uses to authenticate your app with facebook. if you have registered your app on facebook then you will find key for your application on homepage of your registered app.
check this image it shows on top app id

http://i48.tinypic.com/2nas9i0.png